# xmonad spacing between tiles

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I am using the following,

```
layoutHook = smartBorders $ lessBorders OnlyFloat $ avoidStruts $ layoutHook defaultConfig
```

to disable the border when there is only one application in the workspace. What I am trying to achive is to have space between tiles when I have 2 or more. I've tried to add spacing 10 in to the mix which works but it still leaves space when there is only one window in the workspace. is it possible to only have spacing when there is more than 1 tile in the work space?

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to create a layout modifier which recognizes when there is only one window so it does not shrink it.

This is how I solved it in my xmonad.hs:

```
shrinkRect :: Int -> Rectangle -> Rectangle
shrinkRect p (Rectangle x y w h) = Rectangle (x+fi p) (y+fi p) (w-2*fi p) (h-2*fi p)
    where fi n = fromIntegral n
```

This is the function which shrinks given window.

Next you have to define layout modifier:

```
data SmartSpacing a = SmartSpacing Int deriving (Show, Read)

instance LayoutModifier SmartSpacing a
    where
        pureModifier _ _ _ [x] = ([x], Nothing)
        pureModifier (SmartSpacing p) _ _ wrs = (map (second $ shrinkRect p) wrs, Nothing)

        modifierDescription (SmartSpacing p) = "SmartSpacing " ++ show p
```

And finally, function which applies it to the layout:

```
smartSpacing :: Int -> l a -> ModifiedLayout SmartSpacing l a
smartSpacing p = ModifiedLayout (SmartSpacing p)
```

You have to apply  `smartSpacing` to layout you wish to change, e.g. (`Tall` was altered here):

```
myLayout = tiled ||| Mirror tiled ||| Full
    where
        -- Add spacing between windows
        tiled = smartSpacing 3 $ Tall nmaster delta ratio
```

which then you finally use like:

```
layoutHook = smartBorders myLayout
```

For more details, you can take a look at my xmonad.hs [here](https://github.com/matijaSos/dotfiles/blob/master/arch/xmonad.hs)

Also, you might have to add following line to your xmonad.hs in order to compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
```

P.S.

The newest version of xmonad already contains smartSpacing as part of XMonad.Layout.Spacing module, so in this case you can skip defining shrinkRect, smartSpacing and SmartSpacing (the exact same code is already in it).

[newest xmonad smart spacing](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/xmonad/2012-September/013050.html)